# How to force imageSmoothingEnabled to be false

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using several layered canvas plus fabric.js canvas like so:

```
<canvas id="grid" width="1401" height="785"></canvas>
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 1401px; height: 785px; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none;">
  <canvas id="fabric_canvas" class="lower-canvas" width="1401" height="785" style="position: absolute; width: 1401px; height: 785px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
  <canvas class="upper-canvas " width="1401" height="785" style="position: absolute; width: 1401px; height: 785px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;"></canvas>
</div>
<canvas id="keys" width="79" height="512"></canvas>
<canvas id="ruler" width="1024" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas class="helper" width="1401" height="785"></canvas>
```

All these canvas context have the property **imageSmoothingEnabled** set to false but for unknown reason, smoothing is always enabled for all the canvas and querying **ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled** return true even though it was set to false just before.

It seem to be somewhat fabric.js related because **imageSmoothingEnabled** is false when i do not initialize fabric.js canvas but as soon as i initialize it, all of them are set to true.

Smoothing is always enabled under Google Chrome but under Firefox, the smoothing vary (on/off) when i move the fabric.js canvas viewport (panning) or moving the objects.

I use this code to turn off image smoothing for standard canvas (and also for the fabric.js one after initialization):

```
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled    = false;
ctx.oImageSmoothingEnabled      = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled     = false;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled       = false;
```

I also use this to set image smoothing off for the fabric.js canvas:

```
c_fabric = new fabric.Canvas("fabric_canvas", {
    imageSmoothingEnabled: false
});
```

Why does it happen? 
How to disable image smoothing for good?

Comment: I would report this as an issue: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues

Comment: All canvas have the `imageSmoothingEnabled` property set to true even after disabling it so this does not seem related to fabric.js at all, what is strange is if i print each canvas context with `console.log(ctx);` i can see properties such as `mozImageSmoothingEnabled` set to false but `imageSmoothingEnabled` and `webkitImageSmoothingEnabled` (under Chrome) are set to true. I have updated the question.

Comment: Just have tried `new fabric.Canvas("fabric_canvas", {
    imageSmoothingEnabled: false
})` with version 3.6.2 of fabric.js and it seems to be sufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some hours of testing and debugging, the problem was solved, apparently the `imageSmoothingEnabled` property need to be set again after each canvas resizing so this was not related to fabric.js at all, altough when changing fabric.js canvas dimensions via `setDimensions`, the library should set again `imageSmoothingEnabled`, i will propose a patch.

Comment: Not quite correct...Specifically, when you (using FabricJS) change the canvas element's width or height, the browser will always reset that canvas's context to its default condition. (All browsers reset context to default state after resizing). So `imageSmoothingEnabled` will always be reset to that browsers default value. At that point, FabricJS will **re-Initialize its own canvas** which will again force `imageSmoothingEnabled` to again be true. Bottom line: the state of `imageSmoothingEnabled` is still controlled to FabricJS so you must again reset it to false manually after resizing. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**Yep, a look at the FabricJS source says you're right...**

It looks like FabricJS forces imageSmoothingEnabled to be true during the initial creation of the canvas class--even if you set `imageSmoothingEnabled` to false in the options. The FabricJS API method to reset `imageSmoothingEnabled` is private, so you can't use the API to set it to false.

So you will need to wait until FabricJS creates the canvas element and then manually reset its context.imageSmoothingEnabled to false using the multiple cross-browser attribute variations:

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled       = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled    = false;
ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled     = false;
ctx.oImageSmoothingEnabled      = false;
```

Comment: I am doing that already but it does not work, smoothing is always true in my case except under Firefox where it vary, even after setting the property to false after fabric.js canvas initialization, i use the latest version of fabric.js from the repository and it seem the fabric.js function `_setImageSmoothing` is called correctly after init but still, smoothing is true... even if it is set to false.

Comment: See my comment on the answer your posted for more information :-)