# HTML5 Canvas optimisation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently **optimising** my html5 canvas **isometric** game.

So I just implemented two canvases

- The **first** is for the **tiles & walls** (stays static, only drawn once)
- The **second** is for **animated entities** (always animated)

**Both canvases** use the screen resolution (on my computer it's `1920x1080`).

I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` to animate the **second** canvas (the one for entities),
 but I've noticed that **I am using a lot of UC** for a small animated (`70 x 100 px`) user: my game uses about 9% of UC just to draw **a single user** on a `1920x1080` *canvas*.

How can I optimise this?

Edit: demo

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");

// This width/height is to simulate my current computer resolution (my game is fullscreen)

var Mario    = new Image();
Mario.onload = () => LoadMario2();
Mario.src    = "http://i.imgur.com/ZP7NDFh.png"

var Mario2;

function LoadMario2() {
    Mario2 = new Image();
    Mario2.onload = () => ready();
    Mario2.src = "http://i.imgur.com/5suGJkq.png"
}

canvas.width  = 1920;
canvas.height = 1080;

var i = true;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; 
  
    ctx.drawImage(i == true ? Mario : Mario2, 600, 700)
  
    requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

function ready() {
  setInterval(() => i = !i, 500);
  draw()
}
```

```html
Scroll to find Mario
<canvas></canvas>
```

or https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmMVEp

Comment: you can optimize this by careful inspection of your code and replacing ineffective code/approaches with effective ones.

Comment: What is UC? Can you include a minimal code sample which reproduces the issue and state the JavaScipt engine / browser you used to perform the tests? What are the percentages without the background canvas?

Comment: well @Lashane, it's plain `drawImage(img, x, y)` from an actual new Image() object

Comment: @le_m UC's the tab from chrome task manager https://image.prntscr.com/image/1d6e8de84c814fa08a38448f93a00f39.png

Comment: @le_m Here's it https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmMVEp

Comment: why do you need to clear whole canvas `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`? did you draw something outside of mario sprite?

Comment: @Lashane on my game there can be items near Mario or behind him

Comment: so what? why do you clear whole canvas?

Comment: well, Mario's pixels are different on each image so if I only clear the current Mario non-transparent pixels, some of them'd be probably not filled by the new mario image

Comment: clear only part behind mario, something like `ctx.clearRect(600, 700, Mario.width, Mario.height);`

Comment: do you really need to call `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;` every time you draw something?

Comment: yes, otherwise it's not disabled anymore

Comment: @Lashane yeah but what about items or users behind him? They'd be cleared too

Comment: what other items you mean? "animated entities"? aren't you're redrawing them the same way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553012/how-to-force-imagesmoothingenabled-to-be-false

Comment: Yes I am drawing them the same way

Comment: Well I suppose imageSmoothing enabled won't make a big difference

Comment: so, what is the current UC?

Comment: @Lashane It's still high but its around 8 percent

Comment: take a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32221/huge-performance-difference-when-using-drawimage-with-img-vs-canvas and try to replace images with offscreen canvases

Comment: If your `imageSmoothingEnabled` is disabled between two loops it means that you are either using ctx.save/ctx.restore or resetting canvas.width/height. These two sets of operations are really slow (but setting imageSmoothingEnabled should not be).

Comment: @Kaiido No I don't resize my canvas between two loops and I only use drawImage so I don't use ctx.save/restore. It was just because antialiasing was enabled after a resize and I didn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript rendering performance

To get the best performance from any code you must know how code effects performance. The only way to know is by benchmarking your code. If you have a idea that one method will be faster than another you can not rely on hear say or hunch, test it and see. Test it on each browser and device available, test it for every browser and OS device driver update.

The more you test performance the more you will get a feel for what makes fast and what makes slow code.

Below is an example of using the `performance` API to test timing and find some optimizations.

When I ran this with the performance code in it I got, on my machine, a slow machine, a render time of 0.074ms (74 / 1,000,000th of a second), with a few minor tweaks I got that down to  0.069ms. One change I made gave no difference where normally it should have, but because I was actively monitoring performance I could know it made no difference.

The code also shows that most of the time the browser is idle in regard to your rendering

```js
;(function(){   // to keep all vars used out of the global scope
            // Surprisingly that made no effect on frame render time
            // Could have something to do with SO environment.
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
const ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");


// This width/height is to simulate my current computer resolution (my game is fullscreen)

const Mario    = new Image();
const Mario2 = new Image();
Mario.onload = () => LoadMario2();
Mario.src    = "http://i.imgur.com/ZP7NDFh.png"


function LoadMario2() {
    Mario2.onload = () => ready();
    Mario2.src = "http://i.imgur.com/5suGJkq.png"
}

const width = canvas.width  = 1920;
const height = canvas.height = 1080;


var i = true;
var frameTime = 0;
var frameCount = 0;
var startTime = 0
var marioImage = Mario;
 

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; 
function draw() {
    var now = performance.now();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(marioImage, 600, 700)
    requestAnimationFrame(draw)
    frameTime += performance.now() - now;
    frameCount ++;
}
function displayFrameTime(){

    var now = performance.now();
    frameTimeEl.textContent = "Frame interval : " + ((now - startTime) / frameCount).toFixed(3) + "ms Render time : " + (frameTime /frameCount).toFixed(3) + "ms Frame idle : " + (((now - startTime) / frameCount)-(frameTime /frameCount)).toFixed(3)+"ms";
    setTimeout(displayFrameTime,1000);
}
function ready() {
  setInterval(() => marioImage = (i = !i) ? Mario : Mario2, 500);
  startTime = performance.now()
  draw()
  setTimeout(displayFrameTime,1000);

}

}());
```

```html
<span id="frameTimeEl"></span>
<canvas></canvas>
```

**Edit** after posting and running the code the times completely changed, now I get a peek performance of 0.059ms When you test your code you should test it in the environment you intend it to run in as JavaScript is very susceptible to the browsers contextual environment.