# image-rendering: pixelated doesn't work at my javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to add my pixelart to the canvas, but there I met the problem. That image is blurry so I added in canvas css style image-rendering: pixelated. But it's same as before. When I add same style to image outside canvas it's well pixelated. Can someone give me a tip? Why it doesn't work in canvas? Thank you for all replies!

Javascript:

```js
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x - this.size/2, this.y - this.size/2, this.size, this.size)
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    position: relative;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because of `imageSmoothingEnabled` which is part of the Canvas context. ([More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled))

In default it's set to `true` which cause this problem.

Set the `imageSmoothingEnabled = false`;

I highly recommend to set this property to false every time when you change
your canvas's size ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29564875/16068598))